# Is radius epsilon inclusive in DBSCAN/OPTICS algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, dbscan, optics-algorithm

[The original paper](http://www.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/Publikationen/Papers/OPTICS.pdf) and other resources (wikipedia) always define a core-object depending on a radius ε (there must be more than `MinPts` neighbors) using expressions like *within* or *up to*. This leaves a room for interpretation whether this radius is inclusive or not: is an object q a neighboor of p if the distance(p, q) is exaclty ε?

It is obviously very important since all the definitions are based on that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition in the original [dbscan paper](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/KDD/1996/KDD96-037.pdf) for the neighborhood is dist(p, q) <= eps. However, most implementation will use whatever range query the database index supports. In most cases, it will not make a difference and OmG is right that by adding the smallest representable number to eps will effectively change < to <=.

Comment: Ok i did not see the dbscan original paper, so it is inclusive. I realized since then that it does not make any difference in most cases indeed...

Answer (score 0):

I think this not important at all. As there are different methods for finding the value of `epsilon` and none of them is such that exact and also it depends on the structure of the data that you are clustering.

Moreover, if you change the value of `epsilon` a little more than the precision of the language of the development on the specified running machine, this problem can be solved and they are not their neighbor at all! Hence, because of the sensitivity of this problem to the precision of that machine, means it cannot play a vital role in your final result in most of the general cases.

Comment: But both the calculation of the core-distance and the reachability-distance move the value of ε to the exact distance between 2 points, therefore a precision difference cannot make it.